# text color change that corresponds with an image slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a slideshow of portfolio project images playing in a loop on my site's homepage. I also have a list of links with names of all the projects.  Is it possible to change text color in a specific sequence such that when a project image is displayed, the project name/link becomes highlighted?
If so, does it make sense to animate both the images and the text together? Or have them as two separate functions, and just time it correctly so they correspond?

Thanks!

Comment: is my answer what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you have a list of images that are rotating in a slideshow, you also have a list of titles/links that present each one of the items in the slideshow.

A good way to highlight the the correct title when the corresponding slideshow image is active , is to use the slideshow images `id`s

**example**

Below is your slideshow list of images. Each `li` has a unique `id` which we will use to link to the corresponding titles.

```
<ul id="slideshow">
 <li id="project-1"><img src="image-1.jpg" /></li>
 <li id="project-2"><img src="image-2.jpg" /></li>
 <li id="project-3"><img src="image-3.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Below is the list of titles.

```
<ul id="titles">
 <li class="project-1"><a href="/">Project 1</a></li>
 <li class="project-2"><a href="/">Project 2</a></li>
 <li class="project-3"><a href="/">Project 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now you have the basic mark up, you write a function that checks when a slideshow image is being displayed, it then gets the id of that image `li`, and checks whether any of the `li`s within the title's `ul` list has that id as it's class.

If it does, it adds a class to it that changes its colour.

Something like this:

```
if($('ul#slideshow li').hasClass('active'){

    var id = this.id;

    $('ul#titles').find('li.' + id).addClass('highlight');

}):
```

Obviously I am assuming that the current slideshow image/li has a class of active, but this wouldn't be hard to do if it didn't.

Also, the class of highlight will contain css properties of a text color.

Sorry if im way off the mark!

Answer (score -1):

> It may be possible by switch case in
>
> jquery.